# does twitter api support search on specific user timeline?

Tags: twitter

I could not find it in the api.

Is there is an api ,that process the search at client side.

found a way to look for messages that directed to user, however didn't find a way to look up users messages and filter them by hash-tag.

to messages to users by [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-twitsrchapi/index.html) format to:username.

example:

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=to%3Ajohnqpublic

where %3A is ":" character.

usage example, search for google user , android posts:
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23android+and+to%3Agoogle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is to use the key word from instead of to.

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23android+and+from%3Agoogle

Comment: You actually don't need the `+and+` portion, as that's implied.